# How to implement pytest fixture and parametrized arguments as arguments on the same test?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to create a test for a class called `Graph`. I've created a fixture called `my_graph` that just creates a `Graph` instance. Now I want to create a test that accepts the fixture and parametrized arguments that contain a list of inputs and expected outputs.

Here is what I've tried below but I keep getting that the `vertex` fixture is not found.

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_graph() -> adjacency_list.Graph:
    g = adjacency_list.Graph()    
    return g

@pytest.mark.parametrize("my_graph, vertex, expected",
[('A', ['A']), (1, [1])])
def test_add_vertex(my_graph: adjacency_list.Graph, vertex: Union[str, int], expected: List[Union[str, int]]):
    my_graph.add_vertex(vertex)
    assert all([a == b for a, b in zip(my_graph.get_vertices(), expected))
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried adding all three parameters into my method `def test_adding_vertex(my_graph, vertex, expected)` and then decorated it with a `@pytest.mark.parametrize("my_graph, vertex, expected", [('A', ['A']), (1, [1])]))`

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is including the `my_graph` fixture in the `.parametrize(arg_names,...)`.

Since `my_graph` is *already* a fixture, and you seem to be creating a `Graph` instance in the same way for all the tests, you don't need to parametrize it. Just declare it as a parameter of the test function and pytest will find your fixture:

```
# Remove "my_graph" from here ---▼
@pytest.mark.parametrize("vertex, expected", [("A", ["A"]), (1, [1])])
def test_add_vertex(my_graph: Graph, vertex: Union[str, int], expected: List[Union[str, int]]):
    ...
```

I think you got confused from the [@pytest.mark.parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions) example, wherein it shows that all inputs to the test are parametrized. It doesn't have to be like that. **Only those inputs that will have multiple possible values *should* be included in the `.parametrize` declaration**. For  other fixtures (`@pytest.fixture`), just declare them as-is in the test function parameters.

Note also that the [signature for `parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.python.Metafunc.parametrize) expects that the number of `argnames` and the number of `argvalues` should match:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_a, input_b, input_c", [
    ("param_a1", "param_b1", "param_c1"),
    ("param_a2", "param_b2", "param_c2"),
    ("param_a3", "param_b3", "param_c3"),
    ...    
])
```

Here, there are 3 parametrized inputs, so the list should be 3-item tuples. This is a common gotcha when parametrizing tests, and this will produce errors such as "*fixture not found*" or "*must be equal to the number of values*".

So, if for example, you need to instantiate the `Graph` object differently based on the parametrized `vertex` and `expected`, then you need to *also* include the instantiated `Graph` object in the `.parametrize` list of tuples:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self._name = name
        self._vertices = []

...

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "input_graph, vertex, expected",
    [
        (Graph("Graph A"), "A", ["A"]),
        (Graph("Graph 1"), 1, [1]),
    ],
)
def test_add_vertex(input_graph, vertex: Union[str, int], expected: List[Union[str, int]]):
    input_graph.add_vertex(vertex)
    assert all([a == b for a, b in zip(input_graph.get_vertices(), expected)])
```

Here, instead of using the `my_graph` fixture, `parametrize` declares a differently named `input_graph`, and each set of test inputs instantiates a `Graph` object. The renaming is mostly to avoid confusion with your `my_graph` fixture.